# Capture click in a link with jquery

Tags: jquery

In my project, I have the follow page, which is a dashboard with links to all sections of my application:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LigaDesportiva</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="clube.html">Clubes</a></li>
            <li><a href="dirigente.html">Dirigentes</a></li>
            <li><a href="jogadore.html">Jogadores</a></li>
            <li><a href="liga.html">Ligas</a></li>
            <li><a href="usuario.html">Usu&aacute;rios</a></li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">${usuario.nome} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="usuario_perfil.html">Perfil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="usuario_historico.html">Hist&oacute;rico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.html">Sair</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="data"></div>    
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

JS calls

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

JS at the END of the page

```
    $('a').click(function(){
        $.get($('a').attr('href'), function(destino){
            alert('destino = '+destino);
        });
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Draggable Dialog',
            message: 'destino = '+destino+' .Try to drag on dialog title to move your dialog.',
            draggable: true
        });
    });
```

The jquery code in the end of page should capture the 'click' event and display an alert (used now only for test) and a BootstrapDialog, but this is bot happening. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: at a quick glance... if you want to work with the `a` that was clicked, do `$.get($(this)...` instead of `$.get($('a')...`. Otherwise, explain exactly what is happening (or is nothing happening?) and report any errors that show up in your javascript console.

Comment: besides this, when I click in the link, none alert or dialog is displayed, the page in only display in the browser. it's like this code is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that binds a handler to the click event, `$('a').click(function(){` *might* be called before the page has been parsed, in which case the selector `$('a')` isn't getting the anchor elements.

Also, in the handler, you are doing a $.get on *all* of the links in the document. I assume you just want the link that was clicked, which you can get with `$(this)`.

Finally, you need to prevent the default behavior of a click event on an a element.

Try this, instead:

```
<script>
    // The ready event handler is called after the page is ready.
    $().ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(destino) {
                alert('destino = '+destino);
            });
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Draggable Dialog',
                message: 'destino = '+destino+' .Try to drag on dialog title to move your dialog.',
                draggable: true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your JS Part at the bottom of the page to this:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get($('a').attr('href'), function(destino){
            alert('destino = '+destino);
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'Draggable Dialog',
                    message: 'destino = '+destino+' .Try to drag on dialog title to move your dialog.',
                    draggable: true
            });
        });

    });
```

If this doesn´t work, too, maybe you should have to wait until DOM ready is fired. But not sure about this, because your JS code is at the bottom of your page, so the HTML should be loaded when the script block are executed.

You also need `event.preventDefault();` to cancel the link default click action.

Answer (score 0):

```
  write your code inside document.ready()

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(){
      $.get($('a').attr('href'), function(destino){
        alert('destino = '+destino);
     });
     BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Draggable Dialog',
        message: 'destino = '+destino+' .Try to drag on dialog title to move your dialog.',
        draggable: true
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```